# Howcome LineNumberReader is always returning zero in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote the following code to read two different text files. One text file is called the "username" text file, while the other is called the "password" text file. I am creating a login program. In order for the user to login successfully, the line number of the username must match that of the password. For some reason however, my LineNumberReader for both files is stuck at zero, which is strange because I put assertions to avoid this and the assertions did not throw an error. I know they are zero because I printed out each reader. It also keeps printing out "Match found" even when I deliberately put in a wrong username-password match. Can anyone figure this out?

```
    public boolean usernamePasswordCheck(String username, String password) throws         FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/BioStat/username.txt"));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/BioStat/password.txt"));
    String line;
    String line2;
    int userLine=0;
    int passwordLine=0;
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("src/BioStat/username.txt"));
    LineNumberReader lnr2 = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("src/BioStat/password.txt"));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(line.equals(username)){
            //username is found in username list. There is a match!
            //let's get it's line number
            userLine = lnr.getLineNumber();
        }else{
            //username was not found in list, so we should keep reading.
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Userline: "+userLine);
    br.close();
    while((line2 = br2.readLine())!=null){
        if(line2.equals(password)){
            //username is found in username list. There is a match!
            //let's get it's line number
            passwordLine = lnr2.getLineNumber();

        }else{
            //username was not found in list, so we should keep reading.
            line2 = br2.readLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("passwordLine: "+passwordLine);
    br2.close();
    assert(userLine!=0);
    assert(passwordLine!=0);
    if(userLine==passwordLine){
        System.out.println("Match Found");
        matchfound = true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Username and Password don't match");
    }
    return matchfound;
}
```

Comment: maybe this is not the answer that you want... but... if you use one line with format "username:password"? and use f.readLine().split(":")?

Comment: Yeah I thought about this earlier, and I will do it if there really isn't a solution to this problem. But I just don't understand why this isn't working. I'm new to Java so maybe there is something I'm not seeing but it seems like my code should work.

Comment: I see that you are incrementing br and br2 but you aren't incrementing lnr or lnr2. How is it supposed to know what line number to fetch? Also, at what point have you determined that your line number readers are stuck at 0? I don't see any output. Is linereader able to read the contents of the file as well? I think you would be better incrementing the userline and password line for each iteration in its respective loop and setting a boolean if the username or password was found. All together, I think you should put them into one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't advancing your `LineNumberReader` every loop. The `while` loop is taking care of advancing your `BufferedReader`.

You can actually simplify things and just use the `LineNumberReader` without the BufferedReaders because their readLine will give you the text just as a `BufferedReader` will. For example:

```
String line = null;
int userLine=0;
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("src/BioStat/username.txt"));
while((line=lnr.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.equals(username)){
        //username is found in username list. There is a match!
        //let's get it's line number
        userLine = lnr.getLineNumber();
        break;
    }
}
lnr.close();
```

The call to `readLine` on the `LineNumberReader` advances to the next line (and thus will increase the line number as well).

Comment: it works. Thanks. Just one question though, should I close lnr after the while loop or just put a break in my if statement?